# Map reduce with java 8 stream

Tags: java, mapreduce, java-stream

for a class assignment, I have to use java 8 stream to emulate the map reduce but I have a lots of difficulty to get it going. Can someone help me with the mapping (first step)? her is all the code I got so far:
WeatherStationsQ2.java

```
package assignmnent2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.stream.Collector;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class WeatherStationQ2 {

    //Setting up class attributes
    private String city;
    private List<MeasurementQ2> measurements;
    public static List<WeatherStationQ2> stations= new ArrayList<>();


    //Setting up constructor for the WeatherStationQ1 object
    public WeatherStationQ2(String city, List<MeasurementQ2> measurements/*,List<String> stations*/){
        this.city = city;
        this.measurements = measurements;
    }

    //Setting up the setters and getters for the attributes of the object WeatherStationQ1
    public void setCity(String city){
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCity(){
        return city;        
    }

    public void setMeasurements(List<MeasurementQ2> measurements){
        this.measurements = measurements;
    }

    public List<MeasurementQ2> getMeasurements(){
        return measurements;
    }

    //MaxTemperature function to return highest temperature of a given time range
    public void maxTemperature(int startTime, int endTime){

        //Creates a list of the MeasurementQ2 object in the selected time range
        List<MeasurementQ2> tempList = this.getMeasurements().stream().filter(e -> e.getTime()>=startTime)
                .filter(e -> e.getTime()<=endTime).collect(Collectors.toList());

        //Finding the MeasurementQ2 with the higher temperature in the filtered list
        MeasurementQ2 maxMe = tempList.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(MeasurementQ2::getTemperature))
                  .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);

        //Display results
        System.out.println("The maximum temperature was: "+maxMe.getTemperature()+" and it happen at time: "+maxMe.getTime());
    }

    public static void countTemperature(double t1, double t2, int r){
        Stream<List<WeatherStationQ2>> st = Arrays.asList(stations).stream();
        Map<Integer, Double> map = st
        //List <MeasurementQ2> map =  (List<MeasurementQ2>) stations.parallelStream().map(WeatherStationQ2::getMeasurements);
        //Map <Integer, Double> map = stations.parallelStream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MeasurementQ2::getTime, MeasurementQ2::getTemperature));
        /*Stream<List<WeatherStationQ2>> st  = Arrays.asList(stations).stream();
        Stream<List<WeatherStationQ2>> map = st.map(s -> s);*/

        st.forEach(s->System.out.println(s));
    }

    public static void main(String Args[]){
        //Creates a series of MeasurementQ1 object, creates a list and populate the list
        MeasurementQ2 m = new MeasurementQ2(1, 2.0);
        MeasurementQ2 n = new MeasurementQ2(13, 8.1);
        MeasurementQ2 o = new MeasurementQ2(25, 12.5);
        List<MeasurementQ2> mesearements = new ArrayList<>();
        mesearements.add(m);
        mesearements.add(n);
        mesearements.add(o);
        MeasurementQ2 p = new MeasurementQ2(3, 23.6);
        MeasurementQ2 q = new MeasurementQ2(11, 13.8);
        MeasurementQ2 r = new MeasurementQ2(28, 14.5);
        List<MeasurementQ2> measure = new ArrayList<>();
        measure.add(p);
        measure.add(q);
        measure.add(r);

        //Creates the WeatherStationQ1 object
        WeatherStationQ2 WS = new WeatherStationQ2("Galway", mesearements);
        WeatherStationQ2 WS2 = new WeatherStationQ2("Dublin", measure);

        stations.add(WS);
        stations.add(WS2);
        WS.maxTemperature(1, 30);// Applying the maxTemperature method
        WS2.maxTemperature(1, 30);

        countTemperature(19.0,10.8,3);
    }
}
```

MeasurementQ2.java

```
   package assignmnent2;

public class MeasurementQ2 {

    //Setting up class attributes
    private int time;
    private double temperature;

    //Setting up constructor for the MeasurementQ1 object
    public MeasurementQ2(int time, double temperature){
        this.time = time;
        this.temperature=temperature;
    }

    //Setting up the setters and getters for the attributes of the object MeasurementQ1
    public void setTime(int time){
        this.time=time;
    }

    public int getTime(){
        return time;        
    }

    public void setTemperature(double temperature){
        this.temperature = temperature;
    }

    public double getTemperature(){
        return temperature;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getTime() + " " + this.getTemperature();
    }
}
```

The assignment description:
Question 1 [40 marks]
 Create a
class WeatherStation with three attributes (fields): the city where the station is located, the station’s measurements (a list of objects of class Measurement), and a static field stations (a list of all existing weather stations). Also create a class Measurement. Objects of class Measurement should have attributes time (an integer) and temperature (a double number). Add a method maxTemperature(startTime, endTime) to this class which returns the maximum temperature measured by the weather station between startTime and endTime.
THIS PART IS DONE

Question 2 [60 marks]
Add a method countTemperatures(t1,t2,r) to your class WeatherStation from the previous question. The method should return a list which contains two pairs: 1) temperature t1 paired with the number of times a temperature in the interval [t1-r..t1+r] has been measured so far by any of the weather stations in stations, and 2) temperature t2 paired with the number of times a temperature in the interval [t2-r..t2+r] has been measured so far by any of the weather stations in stations.
For computing the result, you need to use an “emulated” MapReduce approach. That is, your code should resemble the MapReduce approach but using only Java >=8 (without a cluster of machines and without any MapReduce software framework). Also, you need to make use of Java 8 Streams (as far as possible) and parallel stream processing (where appropriate).
Finally, add code to your main-method which calls your countTemperatures method using a few test stations and
some test measurement data, and prints the result.

Question 1 is done but I stumble on question 2

Comment: There is too much text, nobody'll read it, please give a minimalist post

Comment: You should make your problem more concise. Too many text

Comment: I edited the question now

Comment: You just copy paste you assignment. meh !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below snippet for all the stations to get the count

```
    long count = this.getMeasurements()
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> Math.abs(e.getTime() - t1) <= r)
        .count();
```

**EDIT**

```
public static void countTemperature(double t1, double t2, int r) {
    stations.stream()
            .map(station ->
                    station.getMeasurements()
                            .stream()
                            .filter(e -> Math.abs(e.getTime() - t1) <= r)
                            .count()
            )
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

With the below call:

```
countTemperature(19.0, 10.8, 8);
```

This is the output:

```
The maximum temperature was: 12.5 and it happen at time: 25
The maximum temperature was: 23.6 and it happen at time: 3
2
1
```

Comment: @AlexAcquier, the above snippet works. See my edited response for the full code.

Comment: Not fully what I needed but it is going in the right direction thanks @mayurmadnani